# Create new google account Selenium C# test

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new to Selenium C# and was testing GMail Create New Account.
And i am stuck in providing value to Month selection.
I've searched online but no reference is available for the same scenario.

Please help.

Ref Foll page :
https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Dtopnav-about-en

Thanks

Comment: How are you planning to solve the Capcha?

Comment: Now worked on it till now. Do you have any sugessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform two steps
1. Click on Month input, its id is `BirthMonth`
2. On popup click on the desired month, months are present inside a div with id as `:monthNumber`. monthNumber is 0 based so for January its is id `:0`.

I am not familiar with C#, Java solution will look like

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Dtopnav-about-en");
// Click on Month dropdown
driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth")).click();  
// Select month from popup
driver.findElement(By.id(":0")).click();
```

Comment: Hi Karna, thanks for your useful reply. The code will be : 

                IWebElement HiddenBirthMonth = null;

                IWebElement HiddenBirthMonthSelect = null; 
HiddenBirthMonth = driver.FindElement(By.Id("BirthMonth"));
                HiddenBirthMonth.Click();

                HiddenBirthMonthSelect = driver.FindElement(By.Id(":8"));

                HiddenBirthMonthSelect.Click();

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to automate the Captcha as it's whole purpose is to stop automated non-human interaction.

However, Gmail allows you to add "+randomString" to an existing email to create pseudo new accounts.

e.g

myemail+foo@gmail.com will forward emails to myemail@gmail.com

If you application under test supports this email format, then you could create accounts in this way.

Alternatively, you can use something like www.dipostable.com to create temporary email addresses